# Shared folders Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a small network with Windows 7 PCs. It's workgroup environment, not domain. I need to setup a file server using Windows Servers 2008 R2 with shared folders. Some folders must be protected by password, but some shares I want to be accessible anonymously. Is it possible at the same time?

Comment: Setting up protection and various permissions is obviously possible. What do you mean by 'accessed anonymously'? Do you want users to access files on your server without you knowing? Or is this access without requiring a username?

Comment: Anonymous access it is access without knowing username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what method you are using to share your files, but this might point you in the right direction.

For allowing anonymouse access you need to set up an anonymouse security object and direct it to whatever file(s) you wish.

A question from serverfault.com might give you an idea:

> Make sure the "ANONYMOUS" security object is granted access. "EVERYONE" doesn't count.
>
> You also might need to allow anonymous access within group policy. Open Group Policy Editor and navigate:
>
> - Computer Configuration
>
>   - Windows Settings
>   - Security Settings
>
>     - Local Policies
>     - Security Options.
>
> Change “Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users” to Enabled

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/271940/no-password-file-share-still-requires-login)

For setting passwords on your folders you should be able to do this through 'Sharing and Permissions' option on the folder right click.